# Prevent tag only edits

Tags: feature-request, tags, review, suggested-edits, too-minor

If an edit that only adds or removes a tag should be closed as "Too Minor," why do we allow them?

Comment: 30?  I thought it was 6...

Comment: Yeah, I thought the cutoff was a lot lower than 30. In any case, a tag has a lot more meaning than a few characters in the body, and a tag change is often important.

Comment: 30 chars is the minimum limit of the whole message body.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Tags are a very important part of a question.  They are what *classify* it.  They are also a big part of finding a question and getting it answered.

They provide visibility in the following ways:

- When users subscribe to tags they get emails with new questions in that tag.
- When users favorite a tag it gets highlighted on the main page and in search
- You can search for questions within a certain tag using the `[tagName]` syntax
- On big sites like Stack Overflow some users only participate in tags that they are competent in; making it easier for the experts to find questions that they can answer
- The biggest tag on a question gets auto-appended to the title for the search engine. This helps with SEO (search engine optimization), making it easier for people using regular search engines to find questions (especially on sites like Arqade, where titles often don't have the game name in them, although the question is tagged with the game name).

The title and tags of a question are what make the question identifiable, which is why you are allowed to edit both without the character limit.

Approving tag only edits help get a question answered because it improves its visibility in the right places.  I'm not saying *all* tag only edits should be approved, sometimes when there is a lot of other things that need fixing I will reject them, but on the whole they are quite useful.

There was even [a privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182586/do-we-still-need-the-retag-privilege) that allows you to edit a question's tags without going through the review system (it was since removed, because of "confusion").

Answer (score 7):

If the post is correct and the only problem with it is tags. I'm totally fine with someone doing a tag only edit.

If the post has a lot of other issues well then it's up to reviewers to reject it.

So I don't think we should prevent tag only edits.