# Can't edit tags only on an existing post

Tags: support, tags, edits

I've just tried to replace an incorrect tag on a SO post (swapping ASP Classic to ASP.net), but the validation prevented it, stating that 'Edits must be more than 6 characters'.

I'm sure I've successfully done this in the past, and it seemed like a useful thing to be able to do. I found [this meta SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174349/prevent-tag-only-edits) post on the subject, which seemed to suggest it should be allowed too?

Should this be possible? Thanks in advance for any info on the subject, and apologies if I've missed any obvious information about this, or am being completely boneheaded at all.

Comment: Can you link the post you are trying to suggest tag edit on it?

Comment: Sure, it's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901476/picture-file-corrupted-or-damaged-after-uploaded-file-from-android-to-wcf-rest-s

Comment: BTW Since you have less than 2k rep your edits need to be approved by at least 3 people. Please make only edits that are worth the time of the reviewers and that should be way more than only a tag change.

Comment: Ah, I see, I thought it would be worth doing, but possibly not useful enough to bother 3 people with!

Comment: Normally if you look for it you are going to find other things to change. Look at the changes the last user made to the post you linked.

Comment: Given how quickly the suggested edit review queue gets emptied, there seems to be an oversupply of willing reviewers! Personally I'm fine with reviewing tag edits, it's generally very quick.

Comment: I agree with Ganesh - the same as with the new posts queue etc, there's never a back log and it's normally cleared within seconds. I don't see any problem suggesting useful edits, even if minor.